# Score in noughts and crosses

Tags: c

M winner checking routine doesn't work. For example, for `x o x`, I get `x` as a winner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char plansza[3][3];
void wczytaj()
{
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[0][0],plansza[0][1],plansza[0][2]);
printf("-------\n");
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[1][0],plansza[1][1],plansza[1][2]);
printf("-------\n");
printf(" %c |%c | %c\n",plansza[2][0],plansza[2][1],plansza[2][2]);
}
int sprawdzenie()
{
if((plansza[0][0]&&plansza[0][1]&&plansza[0][2] =='x' )|| 
(plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][0]=='x') ||
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][2]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') ||
 (plansza[2][0]&&plansza[2][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') || 
(plansza[1][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[1][2]=='x') ||
 (plansza[0][1]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][1]=='x') ||
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='x') ||
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][0]&&plansza[2][0]=='x'))
{
    return 1;

}else if((plansza[0][0]&&plansza[0][1]&&plansza[0][2]=='o') ||
 (plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][0]&&plansza[2][0]=='o') || 
(plansza[0][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') || 
(plansza[0][1]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][1]=='o') || 
(plansza[1][0]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[1][2]=='o') ||
 (plansza[2][0]&&plansza[2][1]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') || 
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][2]&&plansza[2][2]=='o') ||
 (plansza[0][2]&&plansza[1][1]&&plansza[2][0]=='o'))
{
    return 2;
}else
    return 0;



}
   void gracz_x()
{
unsigned int i=3;
unsigned int j=3;
wczytaj();
printf("Podaj wiersz i kolumnę: ");
scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
if(plansza[i][j]!='o')
    plansza[i][j]='x';
else{
    printf("Podaj poprawne współrzędne: ");
    scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    plansza[i][j]='x';
}
}
   void gracz_o()
{
unsigned int i=3;
unsigned int j=3;
wczytaj();
printf("Podaj wiersz i kolumnę: ");
scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
if(plansza[i][j]!='x')
    plansza[i][j]='o';
else{
    printf("Podaj poprawne współrzędne: ");
    scanf("%u %u",&i,&j);
    plansza[i][j]='o';
}

}
int main()

{

char wynik=0;
int kolejka = 0;
while(wynik==0)
{
    if(kolejka==0)
    {
        gracz_o();

    }else{
        gracz_x();
    }
    kolejka=kolejka+1;
    wynik=sprawdzenie();
    if(kolejka==9){
        printf("remis");
        break;
    }
}
wczytaj();
if(wynik==1)
{
    printf("wygryw x\n");
}else if(wynik==2)
    {
        printf("wygryw o\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a very easy way to check your drawing code yourself: Run it. Test it. Try it. Does it print correctly? Then it probably works as it should.

Comment: It helps incredibly if you format the code better: a bit more whitespace and proper indentation reads better for everyone, and could even uncover the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. Im new here, and I forgot I have designation in my language.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if((plansza[0][0]&&plansza[0][1]&&plansza[0][2] =='x' )
```

checks whether `plansza[0][0]` has a value (*any* value that is not `'\0'`), whether `plansza[0][1]` has a value and whether `plansza[0][2]` is equal to `'x'`. It does not check whether the first two values compare to `'x'`.

Thus, you need

```
if((plansza[0][0] == 'x' &&plansza[0][1] == 'x' &&plansza[0][2] =='x' )
```

and so on for all other lines as well.

Comment: It's working perfect. Thanks!
And how about draw ? how can I count move?